# How to get auto_increment particulars using mysqli_fetch_fields?

Tags: php, mysqli, auto-increment

objectice:  to get auto_increment particulars of a field using mysqli_fetch_fields

code:

```
<?php
require_once("dbc.php");
$query="SELECT id, name, age from student WHERE 1>2";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$metas=mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
foreach($metas as meta){
$col_name=meta->name;
$col_type=meta->type;
$col_length=meta->length;
$col_flags=meta->flags;
echo "col_name: $col_name, col_type: $col_type, col_length: $col_length, col_flags: $col_flags";
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Observation:
in mysql prompt

```
mysql> describe student;
Field        Type        Null    Key    Default    Extra
id           int(16)     NO      PRI    NULL       auto_increment
```

but in mysqli

```
col_name: id, col_type: 3 , col_length: 11, col_flags: 49967
```

col_flags value 49967 corresponds to primary key.

Please guide me in getting whether a field is auto-increment using mysqli_fetch_fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate flag bit to test for `AUTO_INCREMENT` is bit 9 (`AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG`) ([Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/group__group__cs__column__definition__flags.html#ga76cd81964ebba4dd1dc0a354ad5f279a)). In PHP you just need to add the `MYSQLI_` prefix. Something like this:

```
$auto_increment = $col_flags & MYSQLI_AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG;
```